# Idle windows shares not removing after Idle Session time

Tags: windows, network-shares, truenas

Afternoon guru's - I have a user that would like to be prompted every time they connect to a network share on a Linux computer (TrueNAS) from a Windows computer with SMB. The user logins and set up are working just as expected, but Windows 11 seems to be remembering the connection until a reboot occurs. So when my user visits (from explorer) \someserver\sharedfolder - they are prompted for authentication, with successful authentication, they can access the share and do all they need to do. When they close out of explorer and go about doing other normal business, they do NOT want windows to remember that connection. So if someone should happen to sit down at the desktop, open explorer, clicks the history in the address bar and reopens \someserver\sharedfolder - it opens right up without prompting for authentication. Because Windows11 is remembering the connection and authentication credentials. I've tried adjusting the Idle session time (min) and set net use /persistent:no via login script to no avail.

Is there some other way to accomplish what I'm looking for (having the Idle session time actually disconnect an idle share after 2 minutes)?  Will I have to write a script for the user to net use /delete * and remap their persistent drives every time they need the share? or am I going about this all wrong?

Any input or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.